# Typescript recursive search

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to do a recursive search in Typescript but for some reason(s) TS can't infer the return type of the function.

```js
function findDirectory(
  directoryId: Key,
  directory: Directory,
) {
  if (!directory) return;

  if (directory.id === directoryId) return directory;
  for (const child of directory.children) {
    const res = findDirectory(directoryId, child);
    if (res) return res;
  }
}
```

Error:
`'findDirectory' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.ts(7023)`

If I'm not wrong, return type should be `Directory | undefined`, what am I missing ?

Comment: You need to explicitly specify the return type with recursive functions.

Comment: This is a [known annoyance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3336) and there was some discussion around supporting this kind of inference, but it was never implemented. Is it out of the question to just add the return type annotation manually?

Comment: Aside from the question itself. I don't think you implementation is valid. Because you are literally only checking the first element from the list.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Thank you for that @jcalz it's done

Comment: If you're answering your own question (which is fine!) you should probably post it as an actual answer and not just an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, the solution was to explicity define the return type for TS to be happy. I suggest @CRice comment for more info

```js
function findDirectory(
  directoryId: Key,
  directory: Directory,
): Directory | undefined {
  if (!directory) return;

  if (directory.id === directoryId) return directory;
  for (const child of directory.children) {
    const res = findDirectory(directoryId, child);
    if (res) return res;
  }
}
```